# 2003 Chevy Malibu Deluxe. Engine counter balancer timing

Tags: engine, chevrolet

I replaced my timing belt.   Now the engine vibrates horribly. I believe the cam timing is 100% but I believe I didn't time my counter  balancer correctly.

The Haynes manual photos and description leave something to be desired.

Can someone proved timing instructions for the cam, counter balancer crank relationship?  I'm pretty frustrated searching.  I'm old and I figure one of you smart young folks can nail this down.  I'll happily trade this piece of junk for 1950 ford truck.  Now that's easy to work.  I'll take the points on that all day.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to do anything in here.  Should I create a new account??

Comment: You sure the spark plug wires (coils, whatever) are firing correctly and in time?

Comment: I'll take that old ford too.  Give analogue or give me death.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best picture i could find. Align the marks of the balance shaft gears. then install the big gear and chain. While installing align the marks on the big gear and crank shaft.

PS this is a timing chain not belt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your fine human.  These Chevys are crap. I'm old and pissed.  Need a v8 instead of this thing. It makes me feel like a little girl ever time I step on the gas.